# Is that possible to include a header file in an indirect way in C++

Tags: c++, include, c-preprocessor, prototype

**First of all, I am a very beginner in programming. So that before answering, please consider that...**

Let's say I have 3 different source code files. First one is **foo.cpp**, second is **doo.cpp**, and third **loo.cpp**. In the **doo.cpp**, I am including the header file of **foo.h**:

```
#include "foo.h"

Doo::Doo(){
//  something
}
```

and in the other file **loo.cpp**, I am including the header file of **doo.h**:

```
#include "doo.h"

Loo::Loo(){
//  something
}
```

My question is; to use in **loo.cpp**, will I have access to create an object from the **Foo** class which is declared in foo.h, without including it in **loo.cpp**, but having included **doo.h** which has the inclusion of **foo.h**. Can I do something like this? :

```
#include "doo.h"

Loo::Loo(){
Foo object = new Foo();
}
```

So like at above, can I reach **foo.h** without including it in the **loo.cpp** but having another source file which has been included **foo.h** in its own source file ? It is simply like an indirect including if it's possible.

Note: *I don't know if I explained my question so terrible, so please feed me back so that I can edit my question to make more understandable.*

Comment: @geza, I edited in that way. Thank you.

Comment: @Ozan: np. Btw, terrible example names, `foo`, `doo`, `loo`. My brain hurts :) Use `A`, `B`, `C`, or `foo`, `bar`, etc.

Comment: "having another source file which has been included foo.h in its own source file" Do you mean `.cpp` by "its own source file" here?

Comment: @geza: .h are source, as .cpp are. In fact all you build from are sources.

Comment: @alk: if you read that sentence carefully, it may mean something else. OP doesn't say, that "another source file" is included in `loo.cpp`. So, the answer to OP's question may be a no. It would be logical to think (for me), that OP means a `.cpp` file there. That's why I'd like to have a clarification.

Comment: @geza: Ahok, so let me rephrase your question: "*Do you (OP) mean .cpp* only *?*"

Comment: @alk: that's even not adequate. :) 'Do you mean a file which has been included to loo.cpp, and it includes "foo.h", or something else'? The question currently means, that if "foo.h" included in **any** source file, then it will be available in loo.cpp. Which is not true, of course.

Comment: Beware of the problems countered by the [Include What You Use](https://include-what-you-use.org/) philosophy.  If your code relies on information from one header (`a.h`), include that header explicitly, rather than relying on another header `b.h` that happens to currently depend on and include `a.h` to provide the access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to use in `loo.cpp`, will I have access to create an object from the Foo class which is declared in `foo.h` [...] having included `doo.h` which has the inclusion of `foo.h`.

Yes.

If

- `loo.cpp` included `doo.h` and
- `doo.h` includes `foo.h`

then `foo.h` is included in `loo.cpp`as well.

You need prototypes. If they were included into any translation unit (.cpp)  you could check by running the pre-processor on it: `cpp foo.cpp` and inspect its output, which in fact is the code fed to the compiler.

Comment: I would mention that depending on declarations from files that are not included directly is usually considered a bad idea. This creates an invisible dependency on the inclusion from the intermediate header.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as indirect including in the way you describe it. If you include `foo.h` into `doo.cpp`, then `foo.h` will be available in `doo.cpp` only, it won't be available in files which include `foo.h`. You need to include `foo.h` into `doo.h` as well, to make contents of `foo.h` available for users of `doo.h`.

`#include` is just simple text processing, nothing more.